# Bind to a listbox, but only show the selected element?

Tags: wpf

I have a collection of objects which I bind to a ListBox, but I actually only want to display the selected element, and not the entire collection.  What's the best way to go about this?  Use a different control?

I think I can do a Visibility ValueConverter which checks the IsSelected attribute -- and if not selected collapses... but I'm still interested in other ideas.

Comment: So you only want to show one ListBoxItem in your ListBox?

Comment: @smoore Yeah, but the user can change the selected item with [previous] and [next]  buttons.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what benefit do you get from using a ListBox if you're not listing multiple items to select from?

Comment: @smoore The observable collection is coming in asynchronously serialized from WCF.  So if I just bind to an element it seems like I'd have to do some ugly backend code when the list is updated.

Comment: Isn't this what they call a ComboBox?

Comment: @erash I don't want a dropdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the entire purpose of a `ListBox` is to display multiple items and provide the user with a way to select them, yes, I'd use a different control.

Or you could do this, which is getting into the territory of stupid:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Anders' answer, there is a way to show only the selected item in an `ListBox`, if, for some reason beyond my imagination, that's really what you want to do:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get WPF to maintain a "current item" for you *without* using a ListBox. In fact, if I'm reading [this blog post](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/09/03/bindtocurrent) correctly, it automatically does so when you set DataContext to a collection.

You can reference the "current collection item" by using a slash in your Path expression.

Since you've already written your own "Next" and "Previous" buttons (which presumably must already hook into this current-item mechanism), you can do away with the madness of a single-item-at-a-time ListBox, and just bind a TextBlock (or whatever) to the properties of the current item:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding /ItemText}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a textbox. On your ViewModel (which I suppose you are binding to) create a property exposing the selected element (make sure to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and bind the textbox to that property.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying something similar and came up with this neat solution:

```
<Expander Header="Elements" Name="FooExpander">
                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding ElementName=ElementList, Path=SelectedItem}">
                                <ListBoxItem.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBoxItem.Style>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="ElementList" 
                         SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo}"
                         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                         />
            </Expander>
```

---

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    FooExpander.IsExpanded = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex == -1);
}
```

Maybe you find it inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combobox instead of a listbox. A combobox shows only the selected item, but you can still choose an item from the whole list. Also, you can use up/down to move through the list.