# Why are there 2 ListBoxItems in the Visual Tree?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, conceptual

I am only displaying the selected element of a ListBox ([yeah I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115936/bind-to-a-listbox-but-only-show-the-selected-element/6116017#6116017)) ... And I am trying to understand why if I have a single ListBox.ItemTemplate with a single child of   ListBoxItem, I have to traverse 2 ListBoxItems to access the element named "thisListBoxItem"?  It seems like there should only be one visual ListBoxItem element.

my XAML

```
<ListBox Name="cjisDisplayItemListBox" SelectionChanged="cjisDisplayItemListBox_SelectionChanged_1">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListBoxItem Name="thisListBoxItem" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <!-- some TextBlocks with bindings here --> 
      </ListBoxItem>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

//First I cast SelectedItem to a ListBoxItem (myListBoxItem)
// then I have to descend to a lower ListBoxItem via the FindName property..

```
private void cjisDisplayItemListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
                        object item = lb.SelectedItem as object;
                        ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
                        ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);
                        if (myContentPresenter == null) return;
                        DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
                        ListBoxItem temp = (ListBoxItem)myDataTemplate.FindName("thisListBoxItem", myContentPresenter);
                        if (myListBoxItem.IsSelected) temp.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is incorrect. The ListBox will automatically wrap the items in instances of ListBoxItem. In your case, you are displaying a ListBoxItem (from your DataTemplate) in the one that is automatically created for you.

You should use [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to set properties on the automatically created ListBoxItem.